# Unable to execute success block after hittng http post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I am making http post request in Angularjs as below.. Service executing successfully , but it's taking long time.. so that before getting response from back end .. control is going to the error block and unable to execute whatever logic we have in success block. can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue

```
 $http({
     method: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/changedneww741",
     data: $scope.compJson,
     headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDQ1NDcwODAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Im9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDQ1MTEwODB9.GIHZpIWclI-X9HL735gpgqnSzLR_CSK7KA6hoJgq27M',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
 }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a promise like this:
1. Create in service a function like this:

```
function yourPost(searchObj) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: appEndpoint,
        data: yourData
    })
}
```

2. In controller (inject your service)

   serviceName.yourPost(sendingData).then(function(response) {
       // success code here
   });

Comment: I have done code changes as u suggested .. still it's giving same issue